# How do I insert tens of thousands of rows without locking?

Tags: mysql, myisam, locking

I have a server that receives data from thousands of locations all over the world. Periodically, that server connects to my DB server and inserts records, one row at a time in rapid succession. There can be up to 6 of these processes (perl) running simultaneously and each may have over 50,000 insert statements, and subsequently, the tables are getting locked.

What I am trying to figure out is what causes locking? Am I better off creating a multi-insert with, say, 100 rows at a time and doing them end to end? What do I use for guidelines?

The DB server has 100GB RAM and 12 processors. It is very lightly used but when these inserts come in, everyone freezes up for a couple minutes which disrupts peopel running reports, etc.

Thanks for any advice. I know I need to stagger the inserts, I am just asking what is a recommended way to do this.

Comment: with InnoDB it should be better because MyISAM is table level locks while InnoDB is row level. InnoDB still has to grab AUTO_INC lock if you have an auto-incremented field, but it's more lightweight than a table lock. So try InnoDB first and then you might consider how to optimize it further

Comment: I cannot simply convert to innodb. There are tables with nearly a billion records.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/concurrent-inserts.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *cannot* get rid of *all* locking.  However, there are ways to speed up what you are doing:

- Use multi-row `INSERTs`.  100 rows at a time will run 10 times as fast.
- As mentioned, switch to InnoDB using `pt-online-schema-change`.  Then put multiple `INSERTs` into a transaction (`BEGIN` ... `COMMIT`).
- The 6 threads could write to 6 different tables (such as `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`), then `INSERT INTO real_table SELECT * FROM tmp_table`.  Even on MyISAM this will run significantly faster because of 6 locks instead of 6*50K.  Read about `concurrent_insert` to see how to avoid 50K table locks into the tmp tables.

Please show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There could be significant other issues, especially with indexes.